# Is it possible to remove remembered Wifi Direct groups from Android programatically?

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct

We've noticed that when a Wifi Direct group is remembered by a device that it sometimes causes problems when the devices are reconnected later. Deleting the remembered groups seems to solve this problem.

It would be nice if we could do this within the application, is this possible?

Simply calling `WifiP2pManager.removeGroup()` does not stop the device remembering them.

[image: Remembered Wifi Direct groups UI]

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to access this methods very easily with no need for reflaction by creating an open android.jar version,
Here is a guide I created:
http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2014/08/use-android-hidden-and-internal-methods.html

Comment: This may fool your IDE into thinking the hidden methods exist, but you can't guarantee availability and consistency between different Android versions without some additional code to check at least that the method exists. Internal/hidden methods are subject to change without notice.

Comment: Correct, I recommend adding a reflection method to verify the method exists, I fixed my blog post, and added reflection code to verify existence of the method

Comment: Is this still the only possibility?

Comment: It still works! while a lot of official stuff got deprecated and removed...